# Join together multiple columns split by a character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

using mssql, if i have data such as:

```
cols: 
id, name,     list1,         list2
1, 'first',  '10;15;30;50', '25;12;15;18'
2, 'second', '50;30;15;10,  '12;25;11;15' 
...
10,'tenth',  '9;2;15;1',    '5;13;17;45'
```

im trying to create rows of results that join each of those list columns together, such as

```
1, 'first', 10, 25
1, 'first', 15, 12
1, 'first', 30, 15
1, 'first', 50, 18
2, 'second', 50, 12
2, 'second', 30, 25
2, 'second', 15, 11
2, 'second', 10, 15
...
10, 'tenth', 9, 5
10, 'tenth', 2, 13
10, 'tenth', 15, 17
10, 'tenth', 1, 45
```

basically, each number of each list maps to the same number at that index (split by ';').
i'm able to use `cross apply` + `string_split`, but it results in a row for each possible combination (id * description * list1_size * list2_size)
is this even possible in sql?

I've also tried using `substring` + `charindex` to manually move around the lists, but this would result in an exorbitant amount of manual columns.

Comment: Do `list1` and `list2` always have exactly 4 members?

Comment: They always have equal numbers, but it's not always 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list have equal size:

```
SELECT 1 AS id, 'first' AS name, '10;15;30;50' AS list1, '25;12;15;18' AS list2
INTO t
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'second', '50;30;15;10', '12;25;11;15';

-- a bit undeterministic, ROW_NUMBER ordered by placeholder 1/0
SELECT id, name, s1.value, s2.value
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS r FROM STRING_SPLIT(list1, ';')) s1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS r FROM STRING_SPLIT(list2, ';')) s2
WHERE s1.r = s2.r;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=daa7292d9c31d5d816f2a31571cf19a9)**

Related: [STRING_SPLIT Add Option to Return Row Number](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896627-string-split-add-option-to-return-row-number)

---

## EDIT:

Using `OPENJSON` to get deterministic position of element in array:

```
SELECT id, name, A.value, B.value
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value, [key] AS rn 
             FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',REPLACE(t.list1,';',','),']')))) A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value, [key] AS rn 
             FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',REPLACE(t.list2,';',','),']')))) B
WHERE A.rn = B.rn;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fde7de5ed902700b4e75b4d592426f06)**

---

## EDIT 2:

Handling list of different sizes:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT id, name, A.value, A.rn
  FROM t
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT value, [key] AS rn 
              FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',REPLACE(t.list1,';',','),']')))) A
),cte2 AS (
  SELECT id, name, A.value, A.rn
  FROM t
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT value, [key] AS rn 
              FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[',REPLACE(t.list2,';',','),']')))) A
)
SELECT id = COALESCE(cte1.id, cte2.id)
       ,name = COALESCE(cte1.name, cte2.name)
       ,cte1.value
       ,cte2.value
FROM cte1
FULL JOIN cte2
  ON cte1.id = cte2.id
 AND cte1.rn = cte2.rn
ORDER BY id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e97bf04c5bd7032005de929b569b64fe)**

Comment: This is exactly why I prefer to use the DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD function. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2 It has the ordinal position of each element.

Comment: @SeanLange I am working on fully deterministic solution using only SQL Server 2017 built-in functionality. ETA 10 min :)

Comment: @SeanLange `OPENJSON` returns key which is respective position in array

Comment: @SeanLange Delivered :)

Comment: Was already a +1 from me but extra kudos now!!! Not something I can use at work since we are not that upgraded yet. Our most recent version is 2014 and that is only on a small percentage of our instances at this point. Working on getting us to migrate everything to 2017.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the lists don't contain more than 4 members, you can use [PARSENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as a shortcut and cross join to a number-table or cte with just the numbers 1-4.

Something like this psuedo-code, assuming you have a Table called `tblNumbers` with a column called "num"

```
SELECT id, name, 
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(list1, ';', '.'), tblNumbers.num) AS L1,
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(list2, ';', '.'), tblNumbers.num) AS L2,
FROM YourDataTable
CROSS JOIN tblNumbers
ORDER BY id ASC, tblNumbers.num DESC
```

If the `List` columns ever do contain more than 4 elements each, you won't be able to use PARSENAME(), but you can still use the CROSS JOIN to a Numbers table approach, with a UDF you would have to write that would get the Nth element of a list.   Pass the List column and the `Num` value to that function just like they're being passed to PARSENAME in my pseudo code above.