# How to create multiple records from comma separated list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2019 to separate comma-separated lists of values.

I have a table that looks like the following

[image]

I would like to run a query on the table produce and output that looks like this:

[image]

From what I've read StackOverflow there isn't a built in function that can split out the commas as I would like. However, I have seen the cross apply `String_Split` function that I think might work, but I could only get it to work on a single column.

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE neighbourhoods3.dbo.timeslots 
(
     year VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     time_of_day VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     day_of_week VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     month VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     season VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     public_holiday VARCHAR(50) NULL,
     public_holiday_minus_1 VARCHAR(50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: `I have seen the cross apply String_Split function that I think might work, but I could only get it to work on a single column` => Cross/outer apply mutliple times

Comment: **[Join together multiple columns split by a character in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56742939/5070879)**

Comment: Also, I'd **strongly** recommend to use the **most appropriate datatype** always - not just make all the columns `varchar(50)` because you're too lazy to think about it.... things like `Month` and `Year` are **clearly** numerical - so you should store them as such - using `INT` (instead of `VARCHAR(50)`). `time_of_day` would most probably best be a `TIME` column

Comment: Dear God, this is some bad schema design.

Comment: I appreciate the schema is terrible, but my main focus is achieving the code I need to get the results.

Comment: But fixing the design is half of fixing the problem...

Comment: your main focus should be on fixing this schema as priority. Not adding additional code dependent on it

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, although SQL Server now supports `string_split()`, it doesn't guarantee the order of the return sets.

So, I recommend an alternative method, such as a recursive CTE.  Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), NULL) as year,
             convert(varchar(max), NULL) as time_of_day,
             convert(varchar(max), NULL) as day_of_week,
             convert(varchar(max), year) as year_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), time_of_day) as time_of_day_rest,
             convert(varchar(max), day_of_week) as day_of_week_rest
      from t
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), left(year_rest, charindex(',', year_rest + ',') - 1)) as year,
             convert(varchar(max), left(time_of_day_rest, charindex(',', time_of_day_rest + ',') - 1)) as time_of_day,
             convert(varchar(max), left(day_of_week_rest, charindex(',', day_of_week_rest + ',') - 1)) as day_of_week,
             stuff(year_rest, 1, charindex(',', year_rest + ','), '') as year_rest,
             stuff(time_of_day_rest, 1, charindex(',', time_of_day_rest + ','), '') as time_of_day_rest,
             stuff(day_of_week_rest, 1, charindex(',', day_of_week_rest + ','), '') as day_of_week_rest
      from cte
      where year_rest <> ''
     )
select year, time_of_day, day_of_week
from cte
where year is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab48600585ce84ff86c810d714c749e6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Lukasz, I tried applying multiple times like the following but it didnt work ```SELECT
  timeslots.time_of_day
 ,timeslots.month
 ,STRING_SPLIT(timeslots.season, ',') AS expr1
 ,STRING_SPLIT(timeslots.public_holiday, ',') AS expr2
FROM dbo.timeslots```

Comment: this seems like an ideal solution, but it seems like a lot work required. TBH, if wouldn't mind if the order wasn't correct for simpler code. Therefore, if I could get the String_Spit function to work, I'd be happy with that

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timeslots.year) as year,GROUP_CONCAT(timeslots.time_of_day) as time_of_day 
FROM `timeslots` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY year
```

Here `GROUP_CONCAT` depends on common column of group by year which used to separte by comma(,) also. Try this

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is the opposite of what they want, and not available in MS SQL Server.

Comment: @smileraj, I'm getting the following error: 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: here 2 rows values or common so which value you want to get in single row by using Group concat .Other than long text its break the word.

Comment: I have just checked out the what capabilities of the String_Function, and I don't think its possible to achieve my requirement with that function .. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/  Sadly, tt can only work on a single column

Comment: I tried the following as a test, but it failed ```SELECT
  month,
  public_holiday,
  VALUE day_of_week 
FROM dbo.timeslots CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(timeslots.day_of_week, ',')```